# Merge 2 data frames with multiple conditions, on ID and column names, automatically based on common columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 large data frames with thousands of columns for each df. I need to left-join the two tables, namely df1 and df2. However, I don't think I'll be able to manually list all of the common columns/keys between the 2 data frames. Below is an example of the data frames:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['a', 'b', 'c'], # Define dictionary
                'test' : [0,0,0],
                'beautiful' : [0,0,0],
                'crazy' : [0,0,0],
                'word' : [0,0,0]})

  id  test  beautiful  crazy  word
0  a     0          0      0     0
1  b     0          0      0     0
2  c     0          0      0     0

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id' : ['a', 'b', 'c'], # Define dictionary
                'test' : [1,0,0],
                'autumn' : [0,1,0],
                'fall' : [0,0,1],
                'word' : [1,1,0]})

  id  test  autumn  fall  word
0  a     1       0     0     1
1  b     0       1     0     1
2  c     0       0     1     0

df_result = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a','b','c'],
                          'test' : [1,0,0],
                        'beautiful' : [0,0,0],
                        'crazy' : [0,0,0],
                        'word' : [1,1,0]})

  id  test  beautiful  crazy  word
0  a     1          0      0     1
1  b     0          0      0     1
2  c     0          0      0     0
```

As you can see from the code, I need to join the two data frames based on two conditions. If `id` matches and `column names` match, then transfer the value from df2 to df1. I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62532419/how-to-merge-two-large-pandas-dataframes-by-mergining-common-columns-and-keeping) with a similar problem to mine, but it is left unsolved. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set the index to `id` and use [`pandas.DataFrame.update`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)
No need to worry about other columns in `df2` because:

> join{‘left’}: default ‘left’
> Only left join is implemented, keeping the index and columns of the original object.

```py
df1 = df1.set_index('id')
df1.update(df2.set_index('id'))
df1.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Output `df1`:

```
  id  test  beautiful  crazy  word
0  a     1          0      0     1
1  b     0          0      0     1
2  c     0          0      0     0
```

Answer (score 0):

The DataFrame.update() method should do it.

```
df1.update(df2)
```

After running this line, we can test to see if it matches your desired output:

```
print(df1 == df_result)
```

Here's the result:

```
     id  test  beautiful  crazy  word
0  True  True       True   True  True
1  True  True       True   True  True
2  True  True       True   True  True
```

Additionally, df1 itself (.update works in place):

```
    id  test    beautiful   crazy   word
0   a   1   0   0   1
1   b   0   0   0   1
2   c   0   0   0   0
```

Comment: Your answer is right, because key and index are same in both dataframes here, but technically you missed the first condition. since the update should happen based on `id`, you need to set the index to `id` on both df's first.

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
# Intersections

df1_columns = set(df1.columns)
df2_columns = set(df2.columns)
intersection = list(df1_columns.intersection(df2_columns))

#Merging based on similar columns

df_merge = df1.merge(df2, how = 'left', on = intersection)
```

I need to clarify, based on similar columns between df1 & df2, df1 stays unchanged and values transfer from df2 to df1 (based on intersected columns)